# SubView willAnimateRotation method is not called

Tags: objective-c, orientation

I have a program with a UIViewController as a Root UIView.

I have added a subView to it.

When I give WillAnimateRotation to the main and the subView.

Only the Root UIViewController WillAnimateRotation is called, but not the subview WillAnimateRotation.

Any solution for it???

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be pass the message along from your root `UIViewController` to the `UIViewController` of your subview:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // you can do some extra stuff here if you like
    [_mySubviewsViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

Remember that this method only applies to `UIViewController` **not** `UIView`.